# XCode 4.5 form validation

Tags: forms, validation

I have a single view app in xcode 4.5 trying to learn form validation. 2 text boxes, 1 label with the total 2 buttons, calculate (multiply) and 1 clear button setting text and label to "", I try to test for "" but getting some weird results. I'm a visual studios user and I'm used to setting a break point, then mousing over a variable and seeing it's value, but xcode is not so kind. I've tried testing for ==nil, but no luck. the first time through if I hit calculate and have never typed in anything my test doesn't work. It's neither nil nor "", probably undefined. I then type 3 in text1, and nothing in text2 and I get my alert
I hit clear and do text2, but not text1, my test works fine. I type in text1, hit calculate, get the alert, then erase text1 and type in text2 and no alert. unless I clear between tries the alert doesn't work. Since I will eventually need to check for numeric I tried

```
 float a=([text1.text floatValue]);
 float b=([text1.text floatValue]);
 if(a==NaN||b==NaN){
 }
```

but this doesn't work for either, I get errors. I know I'm new, but this is a pain...below is my code, please go easy on me...

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  calc2
//
//  Created by russell on 11/18/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 russell. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)button1{

if (text1.text==@""||text2.text==@"") {


    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Blank Values"
                                                     message:@"You cannot multiply blanks"
                                                    delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil]
                                                    autorelease];
    // optional - add more buttons:

    [alert show];

} else {
    float x=([text1.text floatValue]);
    float c=x*([text2.text floatValue]);
    label1.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%.2f",c];
}



}

- (IBAction)button2{
text1.text=@"";
text2.text=@"";
label1.text=@"";
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```